# SQL query to INTERSECT two columns from same table:

Tags: sql, oracle, intersect

I have a table of Employees that looks like this:

```
column_name   | column_id |
employee_id   |     1     |
first_name    |     2     |
last_name     |     3     |     
department_id |     11    |
```

The Employees Table also has a foreign key that references the primary key on Departments Table:

```
column name   | column id |    
department_id |     1     |
```

My goal is to use an `INTERSECT` to show all Employee names that are used as both a first and last name. (i.e: If 'Lee' is a first and last name, I want to display his name specifically).

I am showing the Departments Table because I am not sure whether or not a `JOIN` is required to get the results I want.

First, I got the full list of all first names and last names:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM Employees e

INTERSECT

SELECT e2.first_name, e2.last_name
FROM Employees e2;
```

But I am wanting only the names that appear in BOTH the `first_name` and `last_name` columns.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM Employees e
WHERE e.first_name = e.last_name

INTERSECT

SELECT e2.first_name, e2.last_name
FROM Employees e2
WHERE e2.first_name = e2.last_name;
```

And no rows were selected.

I also tried to use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM Employees e
JOIN Departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id

INTERSECT

SELECT e2.first_name, e2.last_name
FROM Employees e2
JOIN Departments d2 ON d2.department_id = e2.department_id;
```

And this selected ALL the rows.

I am also wondering if there is a way to `INTERSECT` these columns without using a `WHERE` clause at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to build up your query step-by-step.

We'll start by getting a list of names that are both first and last name.  This is where your `INTERSECT` comes in.

```
SELECT e.first_name
FROM   employees e
INTERSECT
SELECT e.last_name
FROM   employees e;
```

Now, you have that list.  Next, you want to show employee details for any employee whose first or last name is anything on that list.  Think of that as "show employee details WHERE (some criteria)".  We'll start with the employee details query and add the criteria later, which will include the `INTERSECT` query above.

So, a basic query of employee details would be:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_id
FROM   employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE ???  -- we need to plug the first query in here somehow.
```

Then, putting it together...

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_id
FROM   employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE  (
         e.first_name IN 
           ( SELECT e.first_name
             FROM   employees e
             INTERSECT
             SELECT e.last_name
             FROM   employees e )
OR       e.last_name IN 
           ( SELECT e.first_name
             FROM   employees e
             INTERSECT
             SELECT e.last_name
             FROM   employees e )
        )
```

Notice we've repeated that `INTERSECT` part and repetition is bad, so we'll make that a common table expression (think "`WITH` clause")

```
WITH   names (name) AS
           ( SELECT e.first_name name
             FROM   employees e
             INTERSECT
             SELECT e.last_name name
             FROM   employees e )
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_id
FROM   employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE  (
         e.first_name IN ( SELECT name FROM names )
OR       e.last_name IN ( SELECT name FROM names )
        )
```

Something like that should do it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I have just started with SQL so the "WITH clause" is unfamiliar to me, I will look into it to get an understanding of what it does, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
-- get intersection of first and last name sets
select distinct first_name as first_and_last_name from employees
intersect
select distinct last_name as first_and_last_name from employees;
```

or this:

```
-- get first names that are also last names
select distinct first_name from employees
where first_name in (select distinct last_name from employees);
```

There is no reason to worry about the `department` table unless you want to include data from that table in your result set or use it to filter your result set.

Answer (score 0):

With EXIST :

```
SELECT first_name FROM employees e WHERE EXIST (SELECT * FROM employees ee WHERE ee.last_name = e.first_name)
```